# Storing a large amount of analytical data

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design

I normally use SQL Server and C# for all projects I do, however I am looking upon a project that could potentially span to billions of rows of data and I don't feel comfortable doing this in SQL Server .

The data I will be storing is

- datetime
- ipAddress
- linkId
- possibly other string related data

I have only ever dealt with relational databases before and hence was looking for some guidance on what database technology would be best suited for this type of data storage. One that could scale and do so at a low cost (when compared to sharding SQL Server)

I would then need to pull this data out based on linkId.

Also would I be able to do ordering within the query to the DB or would that be best done in the application?

EDIT: It will be cloud based. Hence I was looking at SQL Azure, which I have used extensively, however it just starts causing issues as the row count goes up.

Comment: I would imagine Facebook has data spanning several billions of rows. [They use `MySQL`](http://royal.pingdom.com/2010/06/18/the-software-behind-facebook/) (among many other "helper" technologies), so I would imagine sticking with what you know and what works now, and optimizing performance later might make sense here.

Comment: you may be right here, scaling too early as they say.

Comment: From my limited experience in these types of issues, I think it's safe to say whatever you expect is not going to be what actually happens :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this needs to be cloud-based and that you use .Net / C#, if you really are only talking about a few tables (so far just the stated one and the implied "Link" table--source of LinkID) and hence might not need relationships or some of the other RDBMS features, then *one* option is to use Amazon's DynamoDB.  DynamoDB is part of AWS (Amazon Web Services) and is a NoSQL database.  Development and even the initial stage of rolling out a project are made a bit easier by their low-end, free tier. As of 2013-11-04, the main DynamoDB page states that:

> AWS Free Tier includes 100MB of Storage, 5 Units of Write Capacity,
>   and 10 Units of Read Capacity with Amazon DynamoDB.

Here is some documentation: [Overview](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/), [How to Query with .Net](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetQuerying.html), and [general .Net SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/UsingAWSsdkForDotNet.html).

BE AWARE: When looking into how much you think it might cost, be sure to include related AWS pieces, such as Network usage, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Any knowledge on things such as Azure Hadoop or MongoDB?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have no experience with those. I can say, though, that before going too much farther down this path, you should probably be a bit clearer on what you plan on doing with the data. There are several options for storing large amounts of data, but what you intend on doing with it will be the key factor in deciding between them.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are looking for general guidance, I feel it is ok to provide an answer that you have prematurely dismissed ;-).  Microsoft SQL Server can definitely handle this situation (in the generic sense of having a table of those fields and billions of rows). I have personally worked on a Data Warehouse that had 4 nodes, each of which had the main fact table holding 1.2 - 1.5 Billion rows (and growing) and responded to queries quickly enough, despite some aspects of the data model and indexing that could have been done better.  It is a web-based application with many users hitting it all day long (though some periods of the day much harder than others).  Also, that fact table was much wider than the table you are describing, unless that "possibly other string related data" is rather large (but there are ways to properly model that as well).  True, the free Express edition might not meet your needs, but Standard Edition likely would and it is not super expensive.  Enterprise has a nice feature for doing online index rebuilds, but that alone might not warrant the huge jump in license fees.

Keep in mind that with little to no description of what you are actually trying to accomplish with this data, it is hard for me to say that MS SQL Server will definitely meet your needs. But, given that you seemed to have ruled it out entirely on the basis of the large number of rows you might possibly get, I can at least speak to that situation: with good data modeling, good index design, and regular index maintenance, MS SQL Server can definitely handle billions of rows.  Now, whether or not it is the best choice for your project depends on what you are trying to do, what the client is comfortable with maintaining, etc.

Good luck :)

EDIT:

- When I said (above) that the queries came back "quickly enough", I
  meant anywhere from 1 to 90 seconds, depending on various factors.
  Keep in mind that these were not simple queries, and in my opinion,
  several improvements could be made to the data modeling and index
  strategy.
- I intentionally left out the Table Partitioning feature not only
  because it is only in Enterprise Edition, but also because it is more
  often misunderstood and hence misused than understood and used
  properly. Table/Index partitioning in SQL Server is *not* a means of
  "sharding".
- I also did not mention Column Store indexes because they are only
  available in Enterprise Edition. However, for projects large enough
  to justify the cost, Column Store indexes are certainly worth
  investigating. They were introduced in SQL Server 2012 and came with
  the restriction that the table could not be updated once the Column
  Store index was created. You can get around that, to a degree, using
  Table Partitioning, but in SQL Server 2014 that restriction will be
  removed.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. To further elaborate on my hesitation of MSSQL, I currently use SQL Azure for another project. While some tables are into the millions I have one table in there at about 500,000 rows. It keeps timing out on a sql query with an order by in it. Then after a few hours it all comes good again. Multiple tickets raised with Microsoft have only resulted in, yes it looks like it was stalling, we don't know why but you were then transferred to another server and all is ok now. But then I only wait a few weeks for it to occur again. To resolve I now order in code.

Comment: @Adam, does this need to be a cloud-based solution? If so, that is a rather important detail that needs to be in the question. And I have another answer for cloud-based that I can post later today when I have time, as well as an update to this answer with a little more info. But depending on how many rows you expect back, ordering at the app layer might be difficult.

Comment: Yes it will be cloud based. Hence SQL Azure if I choose the MS SQL route.

Comment: @Adam, thanks for clarifying the cloud-based requirement. I have no experience with SQL Azure so cannot speak to that, but I did add a different answer to address cloud-based.